# Rails route -> if no data, check another route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a route

```
  match ":id", :to => "doctors#show", :via => :get, :as => :doctor
  match ":id", :to => "doctors#update", :via => :put, :as => :doctor
```

Which gives me:

```
http://domain.com/ID
```

Now, I created another controller where I also want to have routes almost the same as previous.

```
  match ":id", :to => "professions#show", :via => :get, :as => :profession
```

Which gives me:

```
http://domain.com/ID
```

BUT, I want to create some checking system, for example: If first route didn't found any data, go and check another one. They definetly won't be the same at any time.

---

This is my show code in controller:

```
  def show

     @profession = Profession.find_by_slug(params[:id])

  end
```

Comment: You can use rails redirect_to from first routed controller:action to another.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is the job of controller but not routing.

To rescue no record error

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private

  def record_not_found
    render text: "404 Not Found", status: 404
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-default-500-and-404-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the approach @techvineet pointed in the comments, make a 'router module' that receives the ID or make an "router controller".

This controller/module will try to fetch the Doctor first, if an exception is raised, then it tries to fetch Profession.